# correct syntax to echo variable inside iframe

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, iframe, youtube

I know i am missing something simple. I just want to display this iframe if $video-code exists. Can anyone see what is wrong with this? working in wordpress. error is on the echo line. i've also tried adding .'$video-code'. into the url.

it is displaying the iframe correctly, but the variable is displaying as text in the url. if i call the variable elsewhere in the page without the If statement, it displays correctly.

THANKS for any help!

```
<?php
$key = 'video-code';
$themeta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, TRUE);
if($themeta != '') {
echo '<iframe id="player" width="560" height="315" frameborder="2"     src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$video-code" ></iframe>';
}?>
```

Comment: your variable is `$key` not `$video-code`, so it should be `'.$key.'` as php variables are not parsed inside single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate your `$key`, like so:

```
echo '<iframe id="player" width="560" height="315" frameborder="2" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $key . '" ></iframe>';
```

Comment: hmmm.. it's not working :( the whole thing displays as this

`code`
    "
 

    0" >"
`code`

here is my code
`code`
<?php
$key = 'door-time';
$themeta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, TRUE);
if($themeta != '') {
echo '<iframe id="player" width="560" height="315" frameborder="2" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $door-time . '"  ></iframe>';
}?>`code`

Comment: Where are getting the ID for the video? You need to pass the ID to `$key` variable. Also, you're using `$door-time` inside your iframe code. It should be `$key`. (I tested this before posting and it did actually work. Here's an example: http://codepad.org/rfxcmNss)