# PHP is not loaded in the iframe

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe

Im running a wordpress plugin and i have some problems with it.

When i use this code in a post everything works fine.

```html
<iframe width="362" height="395" src="http://website.comm/<?php 
if ( 0 != get_current_user_id() ) {
  the_author_meta( 'user_description', get_current_user_id() );
  } else {
  echo 'Not logged in user';
  }
?>" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

But when i try to use same code in that plugin i get en error.
The plugin is using *[psfd_php] [/psfd_php]* for php code.

```html
<iframe width="362" height="395" src="http://website.comm/[psfd_php] 
if ( 0 != get_current_user_id() ) {
  the_author_meta( 'user_description', get_current_user_id() );
  } else {
  echo 'Not logged in user';
  }
[/psfd_php]" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The output i get is this.

```html
[psfd_php] 
if ( 0 != get_current_user_id() ) {
  the_author_meta( 'user_description', get_current_user_id() );
  } else {
  echo 'Not logged in user';
  }
[/psfd_php]
```

When i try to use the same code without the iframe code then i get no error.
So there is something wrong.

What is it?
Can you help me with the correct code?

[Click here for the original discussion on wordpress.org/support](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/allow-php/#post-9645284).

Comment: what error do you get for your second attempt? Btw you should be careful about what's in your `'user_description'` field when you insert in a tag attribute; the presence of `"` char for example would close the property declaration

Comment: What's the plugin? URL?

Comment: The error is in the first post. ''The output i get is this'' pure code.
Like this: https://imgur.com/OyGRTj2

Plugin: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/allow-php/#post-9645284

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you're trying to mix two incompatible things: HTML and a WordPress [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode). Shortcodes are meant to be executed inside the WordPress ecosystem. A shortcode - in this case everything inside `[psfd_php]...[/psfd_php]` - needs to be inserted directly into a post/page, it can't just be pasted into HTML and expected to work.

Please read the WordPress documentation on shortcodes and educate yourself on their appropriate use cases.

Comment: But is it still possible to solve this or what?
Im thinking isnt it then possible to just use the shortcode?
Like this
<php shortcode> <iframe> <php shortcode></php shortcode> </frame> </php shortcode>

Comment: [psfd_php]  iframe echo www.website.comm/PHP.CODE.HERE; [/psfd_php]

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824573/correct-syntax-to-echo-variable-inside-iframe

But the correct way to do it.

Comment: if you want to apply a shortcode directly from php code, you can use [the do_shortcode() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/).

Comment: @ANdy forgot to tag you for my last comment so you get notified